# How change the background colour based on a tableview cell value in PYQT

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

I'm new in Python and PYQT and I'm trying to change the background color of the cells of my Tableview based on the value of the cell.
Using some examples I read here, I came up with this code.

```
def openWindow(self):
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_Variacao_Diaria()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()

    file = r'C:/Desktop/Teste_base.xlsx'
    df = pd.read_excel(file)

    df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Date"],columns=["Club"])
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2.to_records())
    headers = list(df3)

    self.ui.t_var.setColumnCount(0)
    for c in range(0,len(df3.columns)):
        self.ui.t_var.insertColumn(c)  
        self.ui.t_var.setRowCount(0)
        for l in range(0,len(df3)):
            self.ui.t_var.insertRow(l)
            for c in range(0,len(df3.iloc[l])):
                self.ui.t_var.setItem(l, c, QTableWidgetItem(str(df3.iloc[l][c])))                    
                self.ui.t_var.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)
                if df3.iloc[l][c] < 100:
                    self.ui.t_var.item(l,c).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(125,125,125))
```

The problem is that when I put this

if df3.iloc[l][c] < 100:                      self.ui.t_var.item(l,c).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(125,125,125))

my code stops in the first cell and does not fill the rest of my TableView with the data. 
How can I make to continuous with the looping??

Comment: Execute it in a terminal or a CMD and check the error message, it seems that your IDE is not properly configured to catch the error messages.

Comment: Hi eyllanesc! I'm receiving the error message "'NoneType' object has no attibute 'setBackground' ". Any idea about It? Thanks!!